# How to call laravel function in Wordpress themes

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, laravel-5, custom-wordpress-pages

I am currently developing a laravel app which I only managed the blog section with Wordpress. Everything works fine. Is it possible to call laravel function in my Wordpress function.php? If yes, how can I achieve that?

Comment: What function do you want to call?

Comment: It makes me sad when I see Laravel and Wordpress integration.

Comment: @swatkins is there any problem with that. I only did that because of the time to build the blog admin from scratch

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin tnx, I want to call query functions

Comment: @Consumateman - no, you use the tools that work best for you.

Comment: i am doing the same. I dont like wordpress. But the client uses plugins etc to build many good looking pages that I really really dont want to write myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will depend on what function you want to call. Some things can be used independent of the framework simply by including the packages, for example [Laravel Collections](https://github.com/tightenco/collect). However if you need more in depth integration you should take a look at the following files.

- public/index.php
- bootstrap/app.php
- bootstrap/autoload.php

It is in these files that the frameworks gets loaded. Meaning that it does all the prerequisites before your application code can run. If you wanted to use Laravel within WordPress you would need to mimic the logic from these files in WordPress. I have never done this before though, so I don't know if you will encounter any namespacing issues or anything else. You might also be concerned about the performance implications of loading WordPress and Laravel on every request. Good luck!